# Middle Sidebar Advertising

Tags: discussion, announcement, advertising

As you all know, advertising is an important source of revenue for Stack Overflow and it helps us support all the sites across the Stack Exchange Network and the resources that go into maintaining and improving the experience on the platform. We are going to be introducing middle sidebar ads, which have been on the main Stack Overflow site for years, to some of the tech sites including Web Applications.

The middle sidebar ads have the same standards as any other ads on the platform. Ads are non-intrusive and static. Ads go through a vetting process to ensure they are appropriate for the communities on Stack Exchange. If you see an ad that may not follow our established standards and guidelines, you can let us know by using the "**report this ad**" functionality. Here is a mockup of what these will look like when two ads are showed (the existing ad placement and the new middle sidebar ad placement):

[image: sample of ads on the middle side bar of the site]

This ad space won’t be available for display until May 10 because we wanted to give you a heads-up before you started seeing them. Ads are an essential line of business for us and we’re committed to giving you advanced notice whenever we introduce a new form of advertising on the network sites. If you have any questions or concerns, please let us know.

Answer (score 2):

I'm interested in knowing which ads will appear on Web Applications Stack Exchange.

As of May 10, 2023, just before the UTC day concludes, the Middle Sidebar Advertising is not displayed. Attached is a snapshot for reference taken from [Do you now have to install the Skype App on mobiles to get to the actual video-chat page?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/170542/311306)

[image: Question sidebar]

Comment: MSB ads are available as of yesterday but they will only be displayed when there are ones that have been vetted and approved. We wanted to give communities a heads up prior to this ad space being available so it wasn't a surprise when people started seeing them.